# Circular dependency was detected in power bi

Tags: powerbi

I have created a measure

NETWORKING DAY- var C1- calendar (max(update date)-max(date one)) Var H1 = DataTable(“Date”,date time, {“01/01/2020} Var c2= except (c1,H1) Var c3= add column (C2,”Weekday”,Weekday(Date,2)) Return Count Tax(filter(c3,[weekday]<6,[date]))

And one other measure with name- NETWORKING DAY2 calculation With different date in calendar

And then have created one bucket column ( If networking day=2 ,”2 days”,”Others”)

And i need same bucket(BUCKET 2) with other measure NETWORKING DAY2 but while creating a bucket column i am getting error like A CIRCULAR DEPENDENCY WAS DETECTED BUCKET , BUCKET2, BUCKET)

Answer (score 0):

In your case not sure why there is a circular dependency, but may be the following description may help you identify what is causing this condition to occur,

consider you have 3 table, tblA, tblB and tblC
Now tblA is connected to tblB and the connection is from tblA to tblB.
tblB is connected to tblC and the connection is from tblB to tblC

Now if you try to connect tblC to tblA in the direction tblC to tblA then power bi engine will raise the concern saying there is a circular dependency.

So, circular dependency is basically a redundant join or reference that we are creating in the model or in DAX.

I hope this will be of some help to you.